# JavaScript runtime error: 'setTimeout' is undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

With the following codes, I got an error "JavaScript runtime error: 'setTimeout' is undefined".

```
<form class="paypalform" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="zengxumin@hotmail.com">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_@count" value="@item.ProductName">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_@count" value="@item.Price">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_@count" value="@item.Quantity">
        count++;
    }
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>

<a href="#" class="placeorder btn btn-primary pull-right">Checkout</a>

<script>
$(function () {

$("a.placeorder").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    var url = "/cart/PlaceOrder";

    $(".ajaxbg").show();

    $.post(url, {}, function (data) {
    $(".ajaxbg span").text("Thank you. You will now be redirected to paypal.");

    setTimeout(function () {
            $('form input[name="submit"]').click();
    }, 2000);
    });
});

});
</script>
```

The codes are supposed to lead to the PayPal checkout web page. But the procession stopped by the text message"Thank you. You will now be redirected to PayPal." Is anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It's `setTimeout`, not `setTimeOut`

Comment: i don't see an input element with name="submit" unless i've missed it. maybe that's just not in the provided snippet? or is that related to the issue

Comment: There was an input element named "submit" and I got the same error. I have corrected the codes. Thanks.

Comment: The problem solved after I corrected the codes. It didn't work for a couple of days even with the corrected codes. Thanks for your replies.